# Flow server and vscode flow extension breaking after updating to catlina and mojave

Tags: visual-studio-code, flowtype

Does anyone encounter this issue? 
`Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.`

This I am getting when I am checking out to old commit and in `locus-dashboard` (*there we do have an old version of flow*) and then switching back to current. Then it starts throwing an error `Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.`.

This are the logs of flow.

```
[Info  - 12:03:15 PM - locus-dashboard-v2/.flowconfig] Found flow using option `useNPMPackagedFlow`
[Info  - 12:03:16 PM - locus-dashboard-v2/.flowconfig] Using flow '/Users/shubanusharma/workspace/locus-dashboard-v2/node_modules/flow-bin/flow-osx-v0.111.3/flow' (v0.111.3)
Unhandled exception: (Sys_error "/tmp/daemon_param688afa.bin: Permission denied")
Raised by primitive operation at file "stdlib.ml", line 316, characters 29-55
Called from file "filename.ml", line 259, characters 7-73
Re-raised at file "filename.ml", line 261, characters 30-37
Called from file "hack/utils/sys/daemon.ml", line 267, characters 2-53
Called from file "hack/utils/jsonrpc/jsonrpc.ml", line 215, characters 4-357
Called from file "src/lsp/flowLsp.ml", line 1555, characters 15-36
Called from file "src/commands/commandUtils.ml", line 13, characters 4-32

[Error - 12:03:16 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
```

I've tried **cleaning up node_modules**, **Clearing** yarn and npm **cache**, **reinstalling** extension.

This seems to be a **Catalina permissions** issue running `flow` with `sudo` works for flow but **vscode extension** have same issue still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a permanent solution but changing `tmp` folder permissions to 777 fixing this.

1. Go to your repo dir and stop server `yarn flow stop`
2. Change `/tmp` dir permissions `sudo chmod 777 /tmp`
3. Start flow server `yarn flow start`
4. Restart vscode flow client by <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>(windows <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) type `restart client` press enter

[EDIT 15-jun-2021]

In most cases just giving permission is enough no need of stopping the server

Also, this not only happens in Catalina happens Catalina onwards

- Mac OS Catlina
- Mac OS Mojave

I've found both contains the issue